# Mixed project solutions in VS2010- managed and native

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, .net-4.0

I've been writing a program that serves in two primary parts- managed UI and native back-end (C# and C++). However, suddenly, Visual Studio thinks that when I try to run the solution, I'm tryng to run the native back-end (a DLL) and throws an error. When I start the exe manually, it won't break on my breakpoints, and suchlike - even though I've enabled mixed debugging. How can I set it back to the original settings- mixed mode debugging and start the managed .exe when launching? I'm in Visual Studio 2010.

I think that this is probably caused because I had a blue-screen in the middle yesterday, and this is the first serious work I've done on it since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to set the managed project as the startup project in Visual Studio.

- Open Solution Explorer
- Right click on the project and select "Startup Project"

Comment: Yeah, this was it. Just confused me because I've never had to do this manually before.